# Python Move/Copy files/Getting names of files from folders without using os.chdir

Tags: python, shutil

Without using os.chdir how to move/copy files (specific files using wild card, say ABC in file name) from folder X (drive D) to folder Y (drive E) while the python script is in folder Z (drive F), ? I will run py script from windows task scheduler.

Comment: use system("mv <srcfile absolute path> <destfile absolute path>"). and find wild card matching files using python regex.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
subprocess.Popen('copy file.exe C:/path/to/copy/', shell=True)
```